# Use existing types in an enum in Rust

Tags: types, enums, rust, algebraic-data-types

Say I have two structs:

```
struct BlankDoc {
    width: u32,
    height: u32
}

struct UrlDoc<'a> {
    url: &str<'a>
}
```

Is there some way to use enums to make a `Doc` type that will be either a `BlankDoc` or a `UrlDoc`, without having to reimplement (copy) all of their fields?

I was thinking something like this:

```
enum Doc {
    &BlankDoc
    &UrlDoc
}
```

or

```
type Doc = BlankDoc|UrlDoc;
```

(Obviously neither of these ways exist.)

What's the idiomatic way to model this in Rust?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap the existing structs in an enum. Eg

```
enum Doc<'a> {
    Blank(BlankDoc),
    Url(UrlDoc<'a>),
}
```

then you can do for instance:

```
fn test<'a>(doc: Doc<'a>) {
    match doc {
        Doc::Blank( BlankDoc { width: w, height: h }) =>
            println!("BlankDoc with w:{}, h:{}", w, h),
        Doc::Url( UrlDoc { url: u }) =>
            println!("UrlDoc with url:{}", u),
    }
}
```

[full playground example](http://is.gd/rlIgLx)

Comment: Nice, thank you. It seems like though there is not a way to make an existing BlankDoc or UrlDoc be matched as a `Doc` without wrapping it. Is that correct? Another idea I had which would sort of accomplish that goal was to make an empty `Doc` trait, but I see that that is not allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You can do [this with a trait](https://gist.github.com/4dd9264949d02e6103e1). But if you want to have a function that decides in his body, like in the first example I gave in the answer, if the Doc is a BlankDoc or a UrlDoc, you have more limited options. There is [Any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html) but in general introspection on traits in Rust is not particularly good or idiomatic

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton here's an [example with Any](http://is.gd/Xyr4DK), for learning purposes, but it's really rare that you would do it this way in Rust. This might be what you had in mind with the mention to the empty Doc trait in your comment?

Comment: Thanks for the detail, the way you specified in your answer is definitely better.